# Is there any Android analog for WPF InkCanvas?

Tags: android, wpf, touch

There is a [touch painting example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/TouchPaint.html) in the API Demos. But this is a source code that should be adopted for specific project. Is there anything that does not require source code inclusion and modification?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.gottabemobile.com/2011/02/16/stylus-and-handwriting-recognition-coming-to-android-tablets/

There are only commercial apps available.

https://market.android.com/details?id=de.softxperience.android.noteeverything&hl=en

No library yet includes an InkCanvas Equivalent for android.